# How to use python-selenium to take full page screenshot in mobile view

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I have implemented full page screenshot by selenium webdriver.
The code as follow

```
import time
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

jenkinsJobName = os.getenv("JOB_NAME")
url = "https://www.ccode.com/sg"

save_fn = "testResult.PNG"

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--headless')
option.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
option.add_argument("--window-size=1280,1024")
option.add_argument("--hide-scrollbars")



driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)

driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)

scroll_width = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
scroll_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
driver.set_window_size(scroll_width, scroll_height)
driver.save_screenshot(save_fn)
driver.quit()
```

that is working fine.

But I use below code to capture full page screenshot in mobile

```
import time
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

jenkinsJobName = os.getenv("JOB_NAME")
url = "https://www.ccode.com/sg"

save_fn = "testResyyult.PNG"

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('--headless')
option.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "iPhone 6"}
option.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
option.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option)

driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)

scroll_width = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
scroll_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
driver.set_window_size(scroll_width, scroll_height)
driver.save_screenshot(save_fn)
driver.quit()
```

The result image just take half of page, not for full page like in the first segement code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrB3j.png)

How can I fix this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *Firefox* for full-page screenshots:

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver

Here is your code modified:

**I have not run this code in context to your use case but I have used it as a part of my own project to get fullscreen screenshots, you will need to check the compatibility of other parameters that you have described with firefox.**

```
import time
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

jenkinsJobName = os.getenv("JOB_NAME")
url = "https://www.ccode.com/sg"

save_fn = "testResyyult.PNG"

option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions() # ------ Changes here
option.add_argument('--headless')
option.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
mobile_emulation = {"deviceName": "iPhone 6"}
option.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
option.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")


driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=option) # ------ Changes here

driver.get(url)
print(driver.title)

scroll_width = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollWidth')
scroll_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight')
driver.set_window_size(scroll_width, scroll_height)
driver.save_full_page_screenshot(save_fn) # ------ Changes here This is the main change, search for this method in the documentation
driver.quit()
```

Also you might want to check the URL that you are taking a screenshot of. Seems like it is unresponsive.

Edit: I also noticed that you want a mobile view. Unfortunately, I think firefox does not return a valid mobile view even after setting

```
option.enable_mobile
```